# Show resulting JSON from API in simple Django template

Tags: python, django, google-visualization

I have this method:

```
def getExchangeRates(): 
    """ Here we have the function that will retrieve the latest rates from fixer.io """
    rates = {}
    response = urlopen('http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=c2f5070ad78b0748111281f6475c0bdd')
    data = response.read()
    rdata = json.loads(data.decode(), parse_float=float) 
    rates_from_rdata = rdata.get('rates', {})
    for rate_symbol in ['USD', 'GBP', 'HKD', 'AUD', 'JPY', 'SEK', 'NOK']:
        try:
            rates[rate_symbol] = rates_from_rdata[rate_symbol]
        except KeyError:
            logging.warning('rate for {} not found in rdata'.format(rate_symbol)) 
            pass
    return rates

@require_http_methods(['GET', 'POST'])
def index(request):
    rates = getExchangeRates()
    fixerio_rates = [Fixerio_rates(currency=currency, rate=rate)
                 for currency, rate in rates.items()]
    Fixerio_rates.objects.bulk_create(fixerio_rates)
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

The API I'm calling has a resulting json like this: `"rates": {"SAR": 4.394498, "INR": 49.836962, and so on...`

How can I sort of "template" that result, in just an easy way, I've tried something like this:

```
<ul>
{% for obj in objects %}
    <li>{{ obj.currency }} - {{ obj.rate}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But obvisouly it's just a blank page.

Any ideas?

I just wanna show the list of currency and respective rates, no fancy stuff.

**EDIT**

Originally, I was using google charts for this, this is the original code:

```
{% block header %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div align="center" style="margin-top:35px;"><a href="/historical"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Historical</button></a></div>

{% endblock %}
{% block body %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart_div"  style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"><div>


<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Currency', 'Rate', { role: 'style' }],
    ['USD', {{rates.0}}, 'gold'],
    ['GBP', {{rates.1}}, 'silver'],
    ['HKD', {{rates.2}}, 'brown'],
    ['AUD', {{rates.3}}, 'blue'],
    ['SEK', {{rates.1}}, 'red'],
    ['JPY', {{rates.2}}, 'yellow'],
    ['NOK', {{rates.3}}, 'orange'],
  ]);



  var options = {
    title: 'Exchange rate overview',
    chartArea: {width: '50%'},
    hAxis: {
      title: '',
      minValue: 0
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: ''
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
//]]>  

</script>



{% endblock %}
```

But this throws me:

```
Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string×
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT 2**

I suspect that since this was originally a Flask application, for some reason, the way I'm doing this is not actually fully correct and the API isn't responding on this Django version, and that could be the source of this error on the chart, I could be wrong tho.

Comment: How you are sending the rates list while rendering the index template? Can you please edit the question after updating the index code also the real code in the template?

Comment: Actually, I was using google charts before, but it thows some errors, so I was aiming to use standard django templating, I can post my original code, gotta edit now

Comment: Done, Thank You, I suspect that maybe the API isn't responding to my method, and that could be the error cause, could be wrong tho

Comment: the google charts error indicates the values for the `'Rate'` column are coming across as strings, instead of numbers, try parsing as float --> `parseFloat({{rates.0}})` -- also, `jsapi` is the older version of google charts, see [update library loader code](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#update-library-loader-code)

Comment: Awesome, now the chart shows up, but no data on it, maybe it's because of the jsapi thing, gonna look to update it, thanks

Comment: Cool, ok, I think the api data is not being crunched for some reason, I'll have to check the python method, but the previous error went away, thanks!